# Next and previous buttons in a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, button, pagination, jstl

I am working on an application with stuts2, spring, spring security , and hibernate.
I want to add NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons in a jsp page, I am using JSTL tags.
I have a list of fistName and lastName.

```
${sessionScope.ListeOfNames}
```

My page jsp must display :

fistName : fistName 1

lastName : lastName 1

and by clicking on NEXT Button, my jsp have to display :

fistName : fistName 2

lastName : lastName 2

Same thing, with PREVIOUS Button:

fistName : fistName 1 (n-1)

lastName : lastName 1 (n-1)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use ajax for this.For example if you place two button in your jsp page.i.e)prev and next.
when you click prev you call ajax and load the result dynamically and replace already existing content with new results.
if you have your content in div tag for example

```
 <div id="result">
some thing
</div>
```

Prev
Next
you call ajax when user clicks the button

```
$("#prev").click(function(){
                       $.ajax({
                        type:'post',
                         url:'ActionName?totalval=page,
                        success :function(data){

                            $("#result").empty();

                            $("#result").html(data);
                        },
                        error :function(){
                          alert("error");  
                        }

                    }); 

});
```

In the hibernate you can set the setFirstResult and setMaxResult function as per user clicking.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont have any idea about Ajax technologie, where can I place this code?

Comment: What about the var "data", can I use this variable for any type (for exemple userClass)

Comment: Yes, in fact, I work with stuts2 in this application

Answer (score 0):

add the below code in your

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
     $("#prev,#next").click(function(){


                        $.ajax({
                            type:'post',
                             url:'actionName',
                            success :function(data){

                                $("#result").empty();

                                $("#result").html(data);
                            },
                            error :function(){
                              alert("error");  
                            }

                        }); 
                });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="result">
    <s:iterator value="something">
    </s:iterator>
    <button id="prev">Prev</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In Your Struts.xml

```
<action name="actionname" class="controller.actionname">
            <result name="success">div_ajax_result.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

div_ajax_result.jsp

```
<div id="result">
<s:iterator value="something">
</s:iterator>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

in each time ajax calling you need to load different result in list.

I hope now you have get a basic idea in ajax.